# How do I sort this data from a json string

Tags: python, json, sorting

```
{
      "version": 51,
      "players": [
        {
          "awards": [],
          "born": {
            "year": 1993,
            "loc": "British Columbia, Canada"
          },
          "college": "",
          "contract": {
            "amount": 750,
            "exp": 2023
          },
          "draft": {
            "round": 4,
            "pick": 2,
            "tid": 19,
            "year": 2011,
            "originalTid": 19,
            "pot": 56,
            "ovr": 32,
            "skills": []
```

this is part of my json file I want to sort OVR on many of the players **

`i.sorted(key=ovr, reverse=True)`

is what I tried and nothing worked any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By usong the [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) function you can use a function to specify what you want to sort by.

Since your question is unclear I'll assume that you have a **list** of dictionaries like in the example you posted in your question. We'll call that list:
`data["players"]` since that's where it seems to be in your JSON.

Then you can sort that list via:

```
sorted_players = sorted(data["players"], key=lambda x: x["draft"]["ovr"])
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Thank you this did help is there anyway I can specifically pick out the OVR in order?

Comment: So you're saying you don't want to sort the players, you just want a list of OVR values?
In what order? Original order or from lowest to highest?

Comment: Highest to lowest

Comment: If you just want the OVR values you can just get `player["draft"]["ovr"]` and put it in a list via a for loop: `for player in data["players"]:`